# Unable to send an email from localhost

Tags: php, sendmail

I changed `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini`, as follows:

**[php.ini]**

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = [mymail]@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"
```

**[sendmail.ini]**

```
smtp_server= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username= [mymail]@gmail.com
auth_password= [mymailpassword]
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=[mymail]@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=localhost
```

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**php code**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (mail($_POST['email'], 'subject', 'Message')) {
        echo 'Success';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
}
```

When I click the submit button, it shows the message "Success" but does not send email. Please suggest.

Comment: Not sure if this is the only problem but you didn't escape your string properly: `sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Comment: I don't understand(

Comment: I added a \ after exe.

Comment: It show "failed" when click submit button. In 'error log text' document show this message: "Connection Closed Gracefully"